# Listbox items not getting moved to other list box in asp,net

Tags: c#, asp.net, listboxitems, aspbutton

I have two list boxes among which one is source and other is destination.

I want to transfer the selected item to the destination list box after the button click event.

I have searched over the internet and found the sample from [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/02/24/moving-listitems-between-two-listbox--server-side-approach.aspx). But in my case its not working.

My ASP source file is :

```
<asp:Table ID="tbvl" Width="100%" runat="server">
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell Width="45%">
            <asp:ListBox ID="lstsource" CssClass="uppercase" runat="server" Width="100%"  Height="140" SelectionMode="Multiple"></asp:ListBox>
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell Width="10%" HorizontalAlign="Center" Height="100%">
            <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" Height="100%">
                  <asp:TableRow>
                        <asp:TableCell Height="25%"><asp:Button ID="btnsd" CssClass="button" runat="server"  Text=">>" Width="40" /></asp:TableCell>
                  </asp:TableRow>
                  <asp:TableRow>
                        <asp:TableCell Height="25%"><asp:Button ID="btnds" runat="server" CssClass="button" Text="<<" Width="40" /></asp:TableCell>
                  </asp:TableRow>
                  <asp:TableRow>
                        <asp:TableCell Height="25%"><asp:Button ID="btnallsd" runat="server" CssClass="button" Text=">" Width="40" /></asp:TableCell>
                  </asp:TableRow>
                  <asp:TableRow>
                        <asp:TableCell Height="25%"><asp:Button ID="btnallds" runat="server" CssClass="button" Text="<" Width="40" /></asp:TableCell>
                  </asp:TableRow>
              </asp:Table>
          </asp:TableCell>
          <asp:TableCell Width="50%">
               <asp:ListBox ID="lstdestination" runat="server" CssClass="uppercase" Width="100%" Height="140" SelectionMode="Multiple"></asp:ListBox>                            
          </asp:TableCell>
       </asp:TableRow>

</asp:Table>
```

And my `Click()` event is;

```
void btnallsd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = lstsource.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (lstsource.Items[i].Selected)
        {
            lstdestination.Items.Add(lstsource.Items[i]);
            lstdestination.ClearSelection();
            lstsource.Items.Remove(lstsource.Items[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

When I click the button page is only getting refreshed but the items are not added to the destination list box.

What should I do to get proper output.

Please help.

Comment: when page is refreshed both listbox also gets refreshed and cause of postback this problem occurs.Make sure this first.

Comment: What changes I should make..? Can you specify @harhar

Comment: you can use ajax update panel control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to ensure that the `ListBoxes` aren't databound on postbacks first. Otherwise you would fill them always with their default items and they would be unselected again.

So use the `IsPostBack` property, e.g.:

```
protected void Page_Load(Object sendeer, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataBindListBoxes();
    }
}
```

You also have to make the button-click event-handler at least protected and **add the event handler** to the aspx markup(or programmatically in codebehind):

codebehind:

```
protected void btnallsd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){//...}
```

aspx:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnallsd" OnClick="btnallsd_Click" ....
```

To find the selected items you could also use Linq:

```
protected void btnallsd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var selected = lstsource.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                   .Where(li => li.Selected);
    while (selected.Any())
    {
        var item = selected.First();
        lstdestination.Items.Add(item);
        lstsource.Items.Remove(item);
    }
    lstdestination.ClearSelection();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Um try this:

```
 private void MoveListBoxItems(ListBox source, ListBox destination)
            {        
                ListBox.SelectedObjectCollection sourceItems = source.SelectedItems;
                foreach (var item in sourceItems)
                {
                    destination.Items.Add(item);
                }
                while (source.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
                {
                    source.Items.Remove(source.SelectedItems[0]);
                }
            }
```

Use: On the click event of your move from 1 to 2 button:

```
MoveListBoxItems(listBox1, listBox2);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
protected void moveRight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
   for (int i = 0; i < lbFirst.Items.Count; i++)
   {
   if (lbFirst.Items[i].Selected)
   {
   lbSecond.Items.Add(lbFirst.Items[i]);
   lbFirst.Items.Remove(lbFirst.Items[i]);
   }
   }
   }
```